# How to get the color of a pixel from a Raw Image Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the color of a specific pixel on a Raw Image but it isn't working. Can you please help? This is the code I used :

```
public RawImage map;

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector3 localPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(eventData.pressPosition);

    Color colour = (map.texture as Texture2D).GetPixel(
        Mathf.RoundToInt(localPosition.x), 
        Mathf.RoundToInt(localPosition.y));

    Debug.Log(colour);
    Clicked();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: and what exactly is the problem? Could you be a bit more specific than `it isn't working`? Are you also sure to access `localPosition.x` and `localPosition.y`? not maybe `z`?

Comment: How is this event raised? From clicking anywhere? Is the pressPosition is the   coordinates to the screen position? Does the image size & resolution correspond with screen size/resolution?

Comment: I am trying to find out the specific pixel clicked on an image that is somewhere on the entire canvas So that I can find the colour of the pixel that was clicked, which might be part of any image that are all subobjects of the canvas.

Comment: It's tricky though, because the images are essentially countries of a map of the world - I think the canvas should have the same dimensions of the world map, and the subobjects should have the exact dimensions of the country's image itself.

Comment: @derHugo I have answered your questions

Comment: Does this have to come from the textures or would it also be okey to simply get the color data of the pixel on the screen in general (might contain lightning etc though)?

Comment: And you didn't explain what is happening what you don't expect .. or where is the issue?

Comment: It could be the colour data in general

Comment: When I click on something on the raw image it gives an output of "1,1,1,1" which is white but I am clicking on something yellow

Comment: @derHugo I have answered your questions